# Return only the highest row number for a partitioned column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to partition a list of submitted machining jobs by the date they were submitted and return a maximum row number for each partition.

I have tried using Group By, but I want to retain all rows in the result. Partition By does what I need, but I want to display all rows except the maximum row number as blank.

```
SELECT     [Created Date]
          ,row_number() over(partition by format([Created Date],'d','en-gb') order by [Created Date] desc) AS [Jobs Submitted That Day]
FROM [UK_App].[dbo].[rvxDevMCRequests]
order by [Created Date] desc
```

Results:

```
Created Date    Jobs Submitted That Day
31/12/2014      1
31/10/2019      1
31/10/2019      2
31/10/2019      3
31/10/2018      1
31/10/2018      2
```

The order by function is not working correctly, and I can't figure out how to display only the highest row number. I would like it to output this:

```
Created Date    Jobs Submitted That Day
31/12/2014      1
31/10/2018  
31/10/2018      2
31/10/2019  
31/10/2019  
31/10/2019      3
```

Comment: what is your dbms name?

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution:

```
SELECT     [Created Date]
         , case when row_number() over(partition by format([Created Date],'d','en-gb') order by [Created Date] desc) 
               = count(*) over(partition by format([Created Date],'d','en-gb'))
          then count(*) over(partition by format([Created Date],'d','en-gb'))
          else null end   AS [Jobs Submitted That Day]
FROM [UK_App].[dbo].[rvxDevMCRequests]
order by [Created Date] desc
```

Comment: I will settle for non-elegant at this point! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
    a.CreatedDate, 
    CASE 
        WHEN y.rnum IS NULL 
            THEN '' 
        ELSE 
            a.JobsSubmitted 
    END AS JobsSubmitted
FROM 
    input a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
        x.CreatedDate, x.JobsSubmitted, x.rnum 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            a.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.CreatedDate ORDER BY a.JobsSubmitted DESC) AS rnum
        FROM 
            input a
    ) x
    WHERE 
        x.rnum = 1
) y 
ON (
    a.CreatedDate = y.CreatedDate
    AND a.JobsSubmitted = y.JobsSubmitted
);
```

SQL Fiddle link for [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/511abf/17): http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/511abf/17

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `format()`?  There is no reason to convert a `date` to a string, especially in this case.

One significant issue is that the column `[Created Date]` has duplicates.  When you `order by` that column, the duplicates *can be in any order*.  In fact, two different `order by`s on the column in the same query can result in different ordering.

The solution to that is to capture the ordering *once* in a subquery and then use that:

```
select [Created Date],
       (case when cnt = seqnum then seqnum
        end) as [Jobs Submitted That Day]
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by [Created Date] order by [Created Date] desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by [Created Date]) as cnt
      from [UK_App].[dbo].[rvxDevMCRequests]
     ) r
order by [Created Date] desc, seqnum;
```

In the above query, `seqnum` captures the ordering, so it is used for the outer `order by`.